# comparing hours and minutes to current time in batch file

Tags: batch-file, comparison

I am currently working on a batch file that will compare the current time to a specified time before starting a program.
i.e: The batch file checks if it's past 10 am. If it is it start the program. If not, it sends a message telling that the program can't be open before 10 am. If it's past 6 pm, the program won't start and a message appears.

This is my code, for now:

```
@echo off
Set _hourAM=
Set _minAM=
Set _hourPM=
Set _hourPM=
If %_nowh% GEQ %_hourAM% If %_nowm% GEQ %_minAM% (
If %_nowh% LSS %_hourPM% If %_nowm% LSS %_minPM% Goto _approved
) ELSE (
```

Comment: To resume you will start a program if the local time is between 10:00 AM and 18:00 PM. If not it display the messsage. Is that correct ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this :

```
@echo off&cls
set "$AM=0950"
set "$PM=1800"
set "$Local_T=%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%"
set "$Sw_T=True"

if %$Local_T% lss %$AM% set "$Sw_T=False"
if %$Local_T% gtr %$PM% set "$Sw_T=False"

If "%$Sw_T%"=="True" (
  echo Path\to\your\program.exe
  exit /b)
cls&echo "YOU CAN RUN THIS PROGRAM ONLY BETWEEN 09:50 AND 18:00"
pause
exit
```

To start your program you have to replace the line :

```
echo Path\to\your\program.exe
```

Bye the path of your program.

Comment: Thanks sachadee, your code does exactly what I wanted to do! Though I don't completely understand how it works, I will analyze it to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a completely different approach.

1. Allocate a "flag folder" somewhere.
2. Make your batch file check for existence of a flag (an empty file by a specific name) in that folder. If it exists, run the program, otherwise deny running the program. (Or you could reverse the logic, if you like.)
3. Create two scheduled tasks, one running at 10:00 AM and creating the flag file and the other running at 6:00 PM deleting it. (It could be another or same batch file accepting a parameter to specify whether to create or delete the flag file.)

Batch files aren't very good at date/time calculation, so, in my opinion, it would be better (and really easy too) to delegate that job to the system component that can do it very well, and just co-operate with it.

Answer (score 0):

This uses a subroutine to transform current time to 24h format just in case current time is in 12h format.

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions

    call :getTime24h now

    if "%now%" geq "18:00:00,00" goto noRun
    if "%now%" lss "10:00:00,00" goto noRun

    echo Here the program should be called

    goto endProcess

:noRun
    echo ERROR: Program can not be run now
    pause

:endProcess    
    endlocal
    exit /b

:getTime24h returnVariable
    setlocal enableextensions
    set "ts=%time%"
    if "%ts:pm=%"=="%ts%" ( set "adjust=0" ) else ( set "adjust=12" )
    for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=:-.,apm " %%a in ("%ts%") do ( set /a "h=100%%a+adjust", "m=100%%b", "s=100%%c", "c=100%%d" )
    endlocal & set "%~1=%h:~-2%:%m:~-2%:%s:~-2%,%c:~-2%" & exit /b
```