# Run batch script continuous in a specific Time Frame

Tags: batch-file, time, automation

I am writing a batch file to continually look for files in a Unix samba shared directory, and if present copy them to a local Windows directory.

I  need this script to run continuously (by means of a loop) between 0800 to 2000 hours.

I have looked in the task scheduler and there does not appear to accommodate times frames as triggers.

Is there a function I can use in a batch script that may allow this?

Comment: Did you perhaps look at what options `ROBOCOPY` has. `/MOT` and `/RH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Time` command (or `Time /T`) shows the current time.

You can add a check in your batchfile, checking if the current time is between 08:00 and 20:00.

Examples of how to compare time variables in batch scripts can be found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613115/comparing-hours-and-minutes-to-current-time-in-batch-file).

Like this, you let your batchfile run always and the batchfile itself checks whether or not it should actually do something.